# Integer inside for loop increases at every line by 2 with statements that do not have any relation to it

Tags: c, function, for-loop, pointers

I am currently experiencing bizarre results in my C program, where inside a for-loop, the variable hex_index increases at every line by 2. It's not time-related or anything. Still, it just increases by every line even though the statements have no relation to it.

ascii.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "types.h"

int
main ()
{
  char *hex = "68747541";
  char output[4];
  hex_to_ascii(hex, output);
  printf("%s", output);
  return 0;
}
```

length.c

```
#include <stddef.h>

/// Returns the length of the passed string based on checking the content 
/// with NULL or @\0 which end a string
int get_str_len(char *string)
{
  int len = 0;
  for (int i = 0; 1; i++)
  {
    if (string[i] == '\0' || string[i] == NULL) return len;
    len++;
  }
}

/// Returns the length of the passed hex string
int get_hex_len(char *hex)
{
  return get_str_len(hex);
}
```

types.c

```
#include "types.h"
#include "length.h"

/// Removes inside a string all control chars and overwrites the passed string
void remove_control_chars(char* string)
{
  int len = get_str_len(string);
  char new_string[len];
  int string_index = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++, string_index++)
  {
    if (string[i] < 127 && string[i] > 31)
    {
      new_string[i] = string[string_index];
    }
    else string_index++;
  }

  len = get_str_len(new_string);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    string[i] = new_string[i];
  }
  string[i] = '\0';
}

/// Converts an hex number to an int
/// If an invalid character is inside the string it will return -1 (Control chars will be automatically removed)
/// @param str The string that should be converted
int hex_to_int(char *str)
{
  remove_control_chars(str);
  int str_len = get_str_len(str);
  int sum = 0;
  int multiplier = 1;

  // Calculating the multiplier for the biggest number (num at index 0)
  for (int i = 1; i < str_len; i++) multiplier *= 16;

  // Adding the multiplied value to the sum and then diving by the base (16)
  for (int i = 0; i < str_len; i++, multiplier /= 16)
  {
    char byte = str[i];
    if (byte >= '0' && byte <= '9') sum += (byte - '0') * multiplier;
    else if (byte >= 'A' && byte <='F') sum += (byte - 'A' + 10) * multiplier;
    else if (byte >= 'a' && byte <='f') sum += (byte - 'a' + 10) * multiplier;
    // Avoiding control characters
    else if (byte < 31) return sum;
    else return -1;
  }
  return sum;
}

bool valid_hex_char(char byte)
{
  return byte >= '0' && byte <= '9' || byte >= 'A' && byte <= 'F' || byte >= 'a' && byte <= 'f';
}

/// Converts an hex number to an dual ascii character and returns it
/// @param hex The string that should be converted
char dual_hex_to_ascii(char *hex)
{
  int value = hex_to_int(hex);
  return (char) value;
}

/// Converts an hex number to an ascii string
/// @param hex The string that should be converted
/// @param output The initialised string which will be overwritten
void hex_to_ascii(char *hex, char *output)
{
  char storage[2];
  int len = get_hex_len(hex);
  int i = 0;
  for (int hex_index = 0; hex_index < len; hex_index += 2)
  {
    if (valid_hex_char(hex[hex_index]))
    {
      storage[0] = hex[hex_index];
      if (valid_hex_char(hex[hex_index+1]))
      {
        storage[1] = hex[hex_index+1];
      }
      else
      {
        storage[1] = '\0';
      }

      output[i] = dual_hex_to_ascii(storage);
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

[Video to the issue](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/786641238006038638/820686109083566140/2021-03-14_15-50-53.mp4) (Watch hex_index, which will randomly increase)

Comment: Node that `NULL` is a null *pointer*, not the string null-terminator (which is only `'\0'`). Also note that all three expressions in a `for` loop are optional, and if you omit a condition it's considered "always true". So instead of `for (int i = 0; 1; i++)` you can have `for (int i = 0; ; i++)`.

Comment: Not sure, but what do you think the `hex_index += 2` expression does at the end of each `for` loop iteration?

Comment: Something somewhere in your code is undefined. This is not a minimized fragment.

Comment: And please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) (like you do in e.g. `string[i] < 127 && string[i] > 31`, what is `127` and `31`?). And learn about [the standard character classification and manipulation functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Comment: And please learn how to use a *debugger* to be able to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the usual way to help with problems like this.

Comment: @AdrianMole, yes, I know that, but the issue was that the value increased while the for-loop was running, meaning every single line of the for-loop basically called the expression.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using the debugger, which is why I saw that issue in the first place

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the range of 31-127 is the range of standard acceptable ASCII characters that are not expanded by the UTF-8, so I am using that to check that the characters that are given are standard ASCII, but I understand what you mean. I am going to change that

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To that, I already know about the standard character classification and manipulation functions. Sadly they are not available to me at the moments since the code snippet is supposed to be used inside low-level kernel functions where those libraries are sadly not provided by the GCC compiler (or rather, I can't use them since they are not usable on that specific platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue that caused this. The debugger had watches left that at every line re-evaluated the values calling the increment at every line. So the code is fine but I made a mistake inside the debugger session.